# Golang and Mongodb query if column does not exist or is null

Tags: mongodb, go

im trying to query mongodb documents (from Go) if a certain column does not exist or if the column value is null, so far with the query i have it only return rows where the column does not exist and leaves out rows where the value is null. here is what i have for the filter:

```html
bson.D{{"$or", []interface{}{
        bson.D{{"date", bson.M{"$eq": bsontype.Null}}},
        bson.D{{"date", bson.M{"$exists": false}}},
    },
```

this query does not give any errors, it just returns only rows where the date column does not exist, leaving out those where it exists and the value is null.
does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this in Go?
all response is appreciated.
thanks...

Comment: Did you try `bson.D{{"date", bson.M{"$eq": nil}}}`

Comment: using nil gives a decode error

Comment: Try this `bson.D{{"date", nil}},`  or  `bson.D{{"date", bsontype.Null}}` You can't use `$eq` in your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to test for *not exists* OR *null* values for a field in a MongoDB collection document.

Consider a collection with three documents:

```
{ "_id": 1, "a": "str-1", "b" : 12 }
{ "_id": 2, "b" : 99 }
{ "_id": 3, "a" : null, "b" : 25 }
```

The goal is to find documents with `_id` values `2` and `3`. The following query does that:

```
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{ "a", nil }})
```

There is another way for performing the same query, using the `$exists` and the `$type` operators (together):

```
cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{ "$or", bson.A{ bson.D{{"a", bson.D{{"$exists",false}}}}, bson.D{{"a", bson.D{{"$type","null"}}}}}}})
```

The above two queries are equivalent to the `mongo` shell queries, respectively:

```
db.test.find({ a: null})
db.test.find({ $or: [{ a: { $exists: false }}, { a: { $type: "null" }}]})
```

Note that the filter `{ a: { $exists: false }}` returns only one document with `_id: 2`. And, the filter `{ a: {$type: "null" }}` returns one document with `_id: 3`. Note the string value `"null"` can be replaced with a number `10` with the same result. This is because the [bson type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types) for `null` is represented as `"null"` or `10`.